# SQL Server data as input to logstash

Tags: sql-server, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

I would like to connect SQL Server with logstash as input. Is it possible or we have any plugin to achieve this.

```
Input{
SQL{
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logstash SQL Server Data Import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674583/logstash-sql-server-data-import)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/), there is no SQL input

Comment: Is there any plugin available

Comment: Is it possible to use any jdbc filter plugin to parse it.