# Elasticsearch - indexing SQL Server table - what is available today?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

This question was probably asked multiple times but I still can't find definite answer.

I have a table in a SQL Server database. Data inserted into the table constantly. Nothing gets deleted or updated. Each row has unique id and date column. I want to index this table in ES. Initial index plus all the new inserts coming in. If possible to create a separated index per day.

What is available today. I see that revers deprecated. Found this [JDBC importer](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc). is that's the one to use? Logstash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What platform are you building this on? Do you have access to .net or are you using some other language. NEST has been one tool we use which allows us easy integration between ES and .net. This allows us to use .net to assemble the data and NEST to build the mapping, and submission. https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/quick-start.html

Comment: I would go with the Logstash JDBC input. How about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674583/logstash-sql-server-data-import

Comment: I am planing to use NEST for reading data from ES.  As more I read I see people still use JDBC river or Logstash to import data.

Comment: @Val, just came across your suggestion and really leaning to this solution. Thanks.