# how to connect or configure elasticsearch with sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, elasticsearch, jdbc

I need to search hundreds of thousands of records. I chose elasticsearch with sql server 2016.

How to configure the elasticsearch with sql server like where to give connection string, where to write query and where to set the fields(columns) of sql server db tables?

I am using Elasticsearch 6.4 version.

Comment: Lakhs or lots? 
In order to be able to answer your question, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You may need [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html)

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31871427/3838328) to see how you can have config file for logstash to push data into Elasticsearch.

I'd suggest you to start reading about basics of Logstash and its [jdbc plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) to know more about it.

Alternatively, if you don't want to make use of logstash, you can make use of client API provided by Elasticsearch if you want to do ingestion via any client application.

Refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html) to see what languages are supported and you can write a client code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @kamal.. Is there any JDBC Importer connecter tool to config between sql and elasticsearch...

Comment: Is there any step by step procedure how to connect sql server with elastic search and query the database , as i am new to this...

Comment: Logstash is that tool :) 

It has simple config file where you can specify what is your input (where you can specify the driver, connector, sql query)  and output (where you can specify elasticsearch server details).

Refer to the link that I've mentioned and follow it. 

Learning how to learn is an important skill and you must go step by step following the docs/links I've provided.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to connect sql server with elasticsearch without using logstash, just i need elasticsearch and sql server along with kibana(to visualize the data). once again thanks..kamal...

Comment: Sure, so without using logstash, you can make use of Elasticsearch Client API

Refer to this link to see what languages are supported and select accordingly. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html

Looking at your question, you might be looking for this
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html